# how to make row span column content start at the top of the column with css and html

Tags: html, css

I have got the following code and would like to know how I can make the text from the column with rowspan 3 start on the top. (because if you look at it now you will find that the text "Nueva columna" is displayed in the middle of the column:

```
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid ;
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Numeros</th>
    <th rowspan="3">Nueva columna</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Uno</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dos</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top`:

```
th[rowspan] {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4zq9zzv7/).

The above will only set `vertical-align: top` to `<th>` elements with a `rowspan` attribute; to style *all* `<th>` elements:

```
th {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4zq9zzv7/1/).

And to style all `<table>` elements that way:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4zq9zzv7/2/).

References:

- [`vertical-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Comment: thank you, it worked!. but do you know why the rows with the rowspan get bigger? I dont want the other rows to move. is there a way to make them "static"?

Comment: I'm afraid not, that's a behaviour I haven't observed; unless you mean that the cell spanning three rows is (three times) bigger than the cells occupying only one row? Which would be entirely by design.

Comment: Sorry, I missed express myself, when I add an image into the column that has the rowspan the other column gets bigger. is there anyway to stop the table doing this?

Comment: That only seems to happen with the `<img>` is bigger than the cell itself ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4zq9zzv7/4/)); which, again, is by design. What should happen?

Comment: i need the table to look something like this:
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Numeros</th>
        <th rowspan="3"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/30/30" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Uno</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tres</td>
        <td>Otra</td>
    </tr>
</table>

And yes, the image is bigger, that's why i used rowspan 2

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
th {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {

    border: 1px solid;

}

th {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Numeros</th>
        <th rowspan="3">Nueva columna</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Uno</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dos</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked!. but do you know why the rows with the rowspan get bigger? I dont want the other rows to move. is there a way to make them "static"?

Comment: I don't see them move or get bigger at all. Do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, I missed express myself, when I add an image into the column that has the rowspan the other column gets bigger. is there anyway to stop the table doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `vertical-align`to `top`like so :

```
table tr:first-child th:nth-child(2){
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lsog2mxv/

Edit : The code above will only target the proper `th`, in case you want your other cells to keep the default behavior. You can remove the pseudo elements and target all the `th`and `td`if you would like all of your cells to have the `vertical-align: top;`.

Comment: thank you, it worked!. but do you know why the rows with the rowspan get bigger? I dont want the other rows to move. is there a way to make them "static"?

Comment: What do you mean "get bigger"? It's the same size for me : http://jsfiddle.net/8xr1hLk7/ (the top left one is the modified one, the two others are the original for comparaison)

Comment: Sorry, I missed express myself, when I add an image into the column that has the rowspan the other column gets bigger. is there anyway to stop the table doing this?